# Information gain calculation using mutual information

Tags: machine-learning, information-theory, mutual-information

I am wondering how to calculate information gain using mutual information. With the help of python's sckit-learn, i have calculated mutual information between two features directly, but there is no library which can calculate information gain. Could you please describe the way to calculate Information gain. Thank you.

Comment: Mutual Information and Information gain refer to the same thing (or could potentially refer to the same thing). $I(X;Y)  = H(X) - H(X|Y)$